# Firebase database security rules for phone authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

For checking whether user is logged in through Google login, I am using this code -

```
"test": {
  ".read": "(auth != null) && (auth.provider == 'google')",
  ".write": "(auth != null) && (auth.provider == 'google')"
}
```

How can I write a security rule to check whether user is logged in through phone authentication?﻿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should allow access to users authenticated with a phone provider:

```
"test": {
  ".read": "(auth != null) && (auth.provider == 'phone')",
  ".write": "(auth != null) && (auth.provider == 'phone')"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This wasn't provided in Documentation here [Security Rules auth variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables)